# Spectral Measures: Numerical Range

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.

Consider a normal operator $N:\mathcal{D}(N)\to\mathcal{H}$.

The goal here is to prove:
$$\langle\sigma(N)\rangle=\mathcal{W}(N)$$

By a previous result one has:
$$\sigma(N)\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{W}(N)}$$
*(Rigorous treatment: [Normal Operators: Spectrum vs. Numerical Range](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/822319/79762))*

As the numerical range is convex this proves the one inclusion.

Now, for a self-adjoint operator one has:
$$\inf\sigma(A)\leq\left(\langle\hat{\varphi},A\hat{\varphi}\rangle=\right)\int_{\sigma(A)\subseteq\mathbb{R}}z\mathrm{d}\nu_{\hat{\varphi}}(z)\leq\sup\sigma(A)$$
As the spectrum is closed this would prove the other inclusion.

But how to adapt this argument to normal operators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key property here is that for probability measures:
$$\int_\Omega f\mathrm{d}\rho\in\overline{\langle f(\Omega)\rangle}$$

As the spectrum is closed it holds:
$$\int_{\sigma(N)}z\mathrm{d}\nu_{\hat{\varphi}}\in\langle\sigma(N)\rangle$$
*(For a unit vector it is a probability measure.)*

Concluding that the other inclusion holds, too:
$$\overline{\mathcal{W}(N)}\subseteq\langle\sigma(N)\rangle$$

---

By definition, for bounded $f\geq0$ we have
$$
\int_{\sigma(N)}f\,d\nu_\hat\varphi=\sup\left\{\sum_j \alpha_j\,\nu_\hat\varphi(\Delta_j):\ \bigcup_j\Delta_j=\sigma(N), \text{ and }\sum_j \alpha_j\,\chi_{\Delta_j}\leq f\right\}.
$$
So we can choose a sequence $\{s_n\}$ of simple functions with $s_n\nearrow f$ uniformly (this is achievable because $f$ is bounded). By choosing a subsequence if necessary, we may assume $f-s_n<2^{-n}$, say. If $s_n=\sum_j\alpha_j\,\chi_{\Delta_j}$, then $f(t)-\alpha_j<2^{-n}$ a.e. on $\Delta_j$. So if we choose one such a $t$ for each $\Delta_j$, we have that $f-\sum_jf(t_j)\,\chi_{\Delta_j}<2^{-n+1}$.

Note that $\sum_j\nu_\hat\varphi(\Delta_j)\,f(t_j)$ is a convex combination of $f(t_1),\ldots,f(t_r)$. So $\int_{\sigma(N)}f\,d\nu_\hat\varphi$ is a limit of convex combinations of points in $f(\sigma(N))$.

For complex $f$, we can write it as $f_1-f_2+i(f_3-f_4)$ with $f_1,\ldots,f_4\geq0$, and we define 
$$
\int_{\sigma(N)}f\,d\nu_\hat\varphi=\int_{\sigma(N)}f_1\,d\nu_\hat\varphi-\int_{\sigma(N)}f_2\,d\nu_\hat\varphi+i\left(\int_{\sigma(N)}f_3\,d\nu_\hat\varphi-\int_{\sigma(N)}f_4\,d\nu_\hat\varphi\right).
$$
So 
$
\int_{\sigma(N)}z\,d\nu_\hat\varphi(z)$ is a limit of convex combinations of convex combinations $\sum_jt_j\,\nu_\hat\varphi(\Delta_j)$, with $t_j\in\sigma(N)$.

Comment: You mean of convex sums sort of? The only thing which came to my mind sort of mean value theorem corresponding to convex sets... Can you explain what you meant?

Comment: Ok is it true that $\int_\Omega fd\rho\in \langle f(\Omega)\rangle$?

Comment: Of course. By definition, $\int_\Omega f\,d\rho$ is a limit of sums $\sum_j\rho(\Delta_j)\,f(t_j)$, with $\sum_j\rho(\Delta_j)=\rho(\Omega)=1$.

Comment: But that is for the Riemann integral, or?

Comment: How do you define the Lebesgue integral, then?

Comment: Do you mind if you or I extend your answer from a hint to a short solution?

Comment: Yes, I'll expand a little later.

Comment: Alright, great, thanks!

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry Martin I only needed the application of the convex property here therefore I opened a whole new thread for the proof ;)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $T$ is normal with spectral measure $E$. Let $\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2},\cdots\lambda_{n}\in\sigma(T)$, and suppose that $\alpha_{1},\alpha_{2},\cdots,\alpha_{n}$ are real scalars in $[0,1]$ for which $\sum_{j}\alpha_{j}^{2}=1$. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be small enough that the closed spheres of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $\lambda_{j}$ are disjoint. Then there are mutually orthogonal unit vectors $x_{j}$ such that $E(B_{\epsilon}[\lambda_j])x_{j}=x_{j}$, where $B_{\epsilon}[\lambda_{j}]$ is the closed sphere of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $\lambda_{j}$. Then, because every $x_{j}\in\mathcal{D}(T)$, the following expression is well-defined:
$$
       (T\sum_{j}\alpha_{j}x_{j},\sum_{j}\alpha_{j}x_{j})=\sum_{j}\alpha_{j}^{2}(Tx_{j},x_{j}).
$$
One has $(Tx_{j},x_{j})\approx \lambda_{j}$, and the smaller the $\epsilon$ that is chosen at the beginning, the closer this approximation can be made. It follows that $\sum_{j}\alpha_{j}^{2}\lambda_{j} \in \overline{\mathcal{W}(T)}$. Therefore,
$$
               \overline{\mbox{co}(\sigma(T))}\subseteq\overline{\mathcal{W}(T)},
$$
where $\mbox{co}(\sigma(T))$ is the convex hull of $\sigma(T)$.

Suppose that $T$ is bounded. Then the spectrum $\sigma(T)$ is closed and bounded. Hence, the closed convex hull of $\sigma(T)$ is the intersection of all closed half planes containing $\sigma(T)$. Every such half plane has the form $\lambda_{0}+e^{i\alpha}\{\lambda : \Re\lambda \ge 0\}$ for some $\lambda_{0}\in\mathbb{C}$ and some $\alpha \in [0,2\pi]$. Such a half plane contains the spectrum of $T$ iff $\sigma(e^{-i\alpha}(T-\lambda_{0}))\subseteq\{ \lambda : \Re\lambda \ge 0 \}$, which is equivalent to $\Re(e^{-i\alpha}(T-\lambda_{0}I))\ge 0$. Hence, $\mathcal{W}((e^{-i\alpha}(T-\lambda_{0}I)) \subseteq \{ \lambda :\Re\lambda \ge 0\}$, which guarantees
$$
           \mathcal{W}(T)\subseteq\lambda_{0}+e^{i\alpha}\{\lambda :\Re\lambda \ge 0\},
$$
for any bounded normal $T$. Hence,
$\mathcal{W}(T) \subseteq\overline{\mbox{co}(\sigma(T))}$ for such $T$
because $\mathcal{W}(T)$ is contained every closed half plane containing $\sigma(T)$. Combining this result with that of previous paragraph gives
$$\overline{\mathcal{W}(T)} = \overline{\mbox{co}(\sigma(T))}$$
for any bounded normal $T$. These arguments do not directly extended to the case of unbounded $T$ because of domain issues that can be avoided using these arguments.

To lift the restriction that $T$ is bounded, consider the restriction $T_{r}$ of $T$ to the subspace $\mathcal{H}_{r} = E\{ \lambda : |\lambda| \le r \}$ for $r > r_{0}$, where $r_{0}$ is large enough that $\mathcal{H}_{r_{0}} \ne \{0\}$. For such $r$, the spectrum of $T_{r}$ satisfies
$$
        \sigma(T)\cap\{ \lambda : |\lambda| < r \} \subseteq \sigma(T_{r}) \subseteq \sigma(T)\cap\{ \lambda : |\lambda| \le r \}.
$$
And $\mathcal{W}(T_{r})\subseteq\mathcal{W}(T)$ because $\mathcal{H}_r \subset\mathcal{D}(T)$ for all finite $r$. There is equality of
$$
              \overline{\mbox{co}(\sigma(T_{r}))}=\overline{\mathcal{W}(T_{r})}.
$$
Because every unit vector $x \in \mathcal{H}$ is a limit of $x_{r}=E\{\lambda : |\lambda| \le r\}x$ as $r\uparrow\infty$, then
$$
   \lim_{r\uparrow\infty} (T_{r}x_{r},x_{r})/\|x_{r}\|^{2} = (Tx,x),\;\;\; x\in\mathcal{D}(T), \\
    \implies \mathcal{W}(T) \subseteq \overline{\bigcup_{r > r_{0}}\mathcal{W}(T_{r})} \subseteq \overline{\mathcal{W}(T)}, \\
    \implies \overline{\mathcal{W}(T)}=\overline{\bigcup_{r > r_{0}}\mathcal{W}(T_{r})}, \\
   \implies \overline{\mathcal{W}(T)} = \overline{\bigcup_{r > r_{0}}\overline{\mathcal{W}(T_{r})}}
             =\overline{\bigcup_{r > r_{0}}\overline{\mbox{co}(\sigma(T_{r}))}}
$$
Because of the first spectral inclusion at the beginning of this paragraph, every convex combination of points in $\sigma(T)$ is in $\sigma(T_{r})$ for some $r > r_{0}$. Therefore,
$$
    \mbox{co}(\sigma(T))=\bigcup_{r > r_{0}}\mbox{co}(\sigma(T_{r})).
$$
It follows that
$$
                   \overline{\mbox{co}(\sigma(T))}=\overline{\bigcup_{r > 0}\overline{\mbox{co}(\sigma(T_{r}))}} = \overline{\mathcal{W}(T)}.
$$